# Java ArrayList: What is Its Abstract Data Type?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, adt

Java's "`ArrayList`" seems like a contradiction to me. An array (static or dynamic) is certainly nothing like a list in a language like c++ or in computer science. What inherits from Java's `List` and yet seems to be nothing like one is rather silly.

**Questions:**

1. What is the abstract data type of the `ArrayList`? Is it a vector (dynamic array), or is it a linked list?
2. Why was the name `ArrayList` chosen? Why was the name `List` chosen for something that uses indexes to access elements and is sometimes random access (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html))?

**NB:** I come from a c++ background where a `list` is a linked list and `vector` is a vector (self-adjusting dynamic array). Is this terminology different in other languages?

Comment: The rationale is that `List` is the interface that offers a set of methods, and `Array` is the underlying implementation of the interface. That implies the asymptotic run times of the underlying ops. E.g. `get()` is O(1) and `remove()` is O(n). Java `LinkedList` otoh is also a `List`, but `get()` is O(n) and `remove()` is O(1).  Java interfaces seldom match up well with classical abstract data types. They're richer. The library source is freely available. It's both instructive and fun to spend time reading the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's implemented with a dynamic array, in your terminology.  (It's actually a static array that just gets replaced when the list needs to be resized.)
2. It's an implementation of the `List` interface that is based on arrays.  Therefore, it's an `Array` `List`.
3. Yes, the terminology is different.  That's not a general use of the term "vector."  "List" just refers to a list in plain English: a number of elements of a type.

Comment: It's just not true that "list in programming means a linked list in computer science."  It's just C++ that has that terminology, and it's not a great terminology.